# Magento2 > Extension > Setup script > Version dependency

Tags: magento2

I've have read the magento2 developer documentation and realized that versioning in UpdateData and UpdateSchema is only possible by using the version_compare in the middle of the upgrade method:

```
class \Magento\Cms\Setup\InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface
{
   public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {
            ...
        }
   }
}
```

Please take a look at the version comparings in:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php

It's pretty messy and sensitiv to errors while declaring version dependencies programmatically.
I think that the way Magento 1 do is far better.
Just reminding myself about m1-sales-module, which include over 117 upgrade scripts:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.6.2-0.7.0.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.0-0.7.1.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.1-0.7.2.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.2-0.7.3.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.9-0.7.10.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.0-0.8.1.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.1-0.8.2.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.11-0.8.12.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.12-0.8.13.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.13-0.8.14.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.14-0.8.15.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.15-0.8.16.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.16-0.8.17.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.17-0.8.18.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.18-0.8.19.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.19-0.8.20.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.20-0.8.21.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.2-0.8.3.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.21-0.8.22.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.22-0.8.23.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.23-0.8.24.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.24-0.8.25.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.25-0.8.26.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.26-0.8.27.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.27-0.8.28.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.28-0.8.29.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.29-0.9.0.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.3-0.8.4.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.6-0.8.7.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.7-0.8.8.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.8-0.8.9.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.0-0.9.1.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.10-0.9.11.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.1-0.9.2.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.11-0.9.12.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.12-0.9.13.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.13-0.9.14.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.14-0.9.15.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.15-0.9.16.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-0.9.17.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.17-0.9.18.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.18-0.9.19.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.19-0.9.20.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.20-0.9.21.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.2-0.9.3.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.21-0.9.22.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.22-0.9.23.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.23-0.9.24.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.24-0.9.25.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.25-0.9.26.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.26-0.9.27.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.27-0.9.28.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.28-0.9.29.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.29-0.9.30.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.30-0.9.31.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.3-0.9.4.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.31-0.9.32.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.32-0.9.33.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.33-0.9.34.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.34-0.9.35.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.35-0.9.36.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.36-0.9.37.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.37-0.9.38.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.38-0.9.39.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.39-0.9.40.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.40-0.9.41.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.4-0.9.5.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.41-0.9.42.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.42-0.9.43.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.43-0.9.44.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.44-0.9.45.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.45-0.9.46.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.46-0.9.47.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.47-0.9.48.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.48-0.9.49.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.49-0.9.50.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.50-0.9.51.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.5-0.9.6.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.51-0.9.52.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.52-0.9.53.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.53-0.9.54.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.54-0.9.55.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.55-0.9.56.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.6-0.9.7.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.7-0.9.8.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.8-0.9.9.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.9-0.9.10.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.3.99-1.4.0.0.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0-1.4.0.1.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.1-1.4.0.2.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.15-1.4.0.16.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.16-1.4.0.17.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.17-1.4.0.18.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.18-1.4.0.19.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.19-1.4.0.20.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.20-1.4.0.21.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.21-1.4.0.22.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.2-1.4.0.3.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.22-1.4.0.23.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.23-1.4.0.24.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.24-1.4.0.25.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.3-1.4.0.4.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.4-1.4.0.5.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.5-1.4.0.6.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.6-1.4.0.7.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.7-1.4.0.8.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.8-1.4.0.15.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.2-1.6.0.3.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.3-1.6.0.4.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.4-1.6.0.5.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6-1.6.0.7.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.7-1.6.0.8.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.8-1.6.0.9.php
```

Now, imagine how the m2 Setup file would grow over time.
Currently, there are 7 version dependencies that are declared programmatically:

```
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php:29:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2', '<')) {
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php:68:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.3', '<')) {
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php:72:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.4', '<')) {
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php:87:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.5', '<')) {
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeData.php:68:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeData.php:71:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.5', '<')) {
app/code/Magento/Sales/Setup/UpgradeData.php:75:        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.6', '<')) {
```

What I would like to know is:

1. Is it possible to write the M2 upgrade scripts in the way of M1?
2. What do you think about this confusing messy way writing version dependent upgrade scripts?
3. What was the internal purpose of the Magento architects to redesign this approach?